# Check for true values for different keys in two different array items in JSON Validation

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Consider if I have an array that looks something like the example below:

```
          {
            "id": 1,
            "published": true,
            "available": false
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "published": false,
            "available": true
          }
```

There can be many items in the array, say up to 10. I  need to check all the items separately for `published` and `available`. 
The JSON validation should check all the items and **PASS** if any of one of the array items has `true`value for `published` atleast once **AND** `true` value for `available` atleast once as well. It could be in the same item or different items. The validation should fail if any of these properties were not `true` even once in any of the array items. Any ideas on how could I get that done?
I have tried

**anyOF**: checks for one of the properties and passes the validation,

**allOf**: checks for every instance and fails validation for every instance it is false (need to pass even if it the key is `true` once),

**contains**: can be used only once in the validation and ends up checking for both the keys to be true in a single item.
Any suggestions on how can I get around this, would be really helpful! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use "contains" more than once -- just put it inside an "allOf" or "anyOf".  So, something like this?

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object"
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "contains": {
        "properties": {
          "published": { "const": true }
        }
    },
    {
      "contains": {
        "properties": {
          "available": { "const": true }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was doing the opposite. I had put the "allOf" inside "contains", so obviously didn't work. This worked!!